# Magento 2 Is there a way to use product chooser in ui component form (NOT BLOCK)?

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, adminhtml, ui

Im building module using **ui components** and need product chooser in my form. But can't find any useful info related to product chooser implementation using ui component.
Is it possible to do this without block?
Thanks.

[image: product chooser m2]

Comment: This may be what you need https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/select/ I use it in UI form for product chooser